# Create Json Document using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'd like to create a Json document using Jackson. I know we can do this using `JsonGenerator`. However, an alternative to this is to do the `ObjectMapper`.

I was wondering which one would be more performant?

I want something that can create Json documents with very low overhead (in terms of both memory and time).

I have been referencing this (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance) but it does not explicitly answer my question.

Comment: *"very low overhead"* - can you be a lot more specific about your setup and your needs? How many document generations per second? Have you tried something already and found a problem with it?

Comment: lowest overhead: do not use Jackson! You want to use Jackson because it is easy to map from objects to JSON? use the ObjectMapper. If you are looking for an easy way to write some values into a json document, use the JsonGenerator.

Comment: Really the only way to be sure is to run a proper benchmark for your own particular environment and make a judgement which is better, or whether there really isn't much difference. It's possible you can describe your needs well enough to get a non-opinionated answer, but probably a lot quicker to just test it yourself.

Comment: @Meiko - what should I be using ...?

Comment: what type and quantity of data you have to write into the json document?

Comment: @AndrewRegan - Thanks for the suggestion. However, I don't want a solution for any "particular" environment. I'd like to generate json documents as fast as possible (no particular number here) and without using too much memory.

Comment: @Meiko - mostly primitive types (perhaps strings, integers, etc). It would be less than 1 GB. (I meant what should I be using if not Jackson)

Comment: serialization performance comparison: http://rick-hightower.blogspot.de/2014/04/new-json-serialization-benchmark.html (but I never used boon ;)

deserialization performance comparison Jettison, GSON, Jackson, JSONP: http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

Comment: My point is that there's likely no utterly-superior implementation, but by testing yourself you can be sure what works best for your actual needs, rather than you having to describe them in great detail to people who may only have blogposts with *generic performance stats* from a couple of years ago to go on.